# How can I use a 401 error from the server to create a frontend error notice?

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

The server sends back a 401 error when the credentials entered into the inputs are invalid. How can I use this response to create a frontend notice? This is what I tried which doesn't work.

```js
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default async function loginFunction(body: Auth) {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/auth/login";

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    const errorResponse = await response.json();
    throw new Error(
      `Request failed with status ${response.status}, ${errorResponse}`
    );
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  Cookies.set("token", data.token, {
    expires: 7,
    path: "/",
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "strict",
  });

  return data;
}
```

```js
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useTransition, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import loginFunction from "@/lib/loginUser";

export const LoginForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    loginEmail: "",
    loginPassword: "",
  });

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  function handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const body: Auth = {
      email: formData.loginEmail,
      password: formData.loginPassword,
    };

    const emailRegex =
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    const isValidEmail = emailRegex.test(formData.loginEmail);

    if (!isValidEmail) {
      setEmailError(true);
      return;
    }
    try {
      await startTransition(async () => {
        await loginFunction(body);
        router.push("/profile");
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error instanceof Error &&
        error.message.includes("Error: Request failed with status 401")
      ) {
        setErrorMessage("Invalid Credentials.");
      } else {
        setErrorMessage("Login failed. Please try again later.");
        console.error("Login failed:", error);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="loginEmail" className="form-label">
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          className="form-control"
          id="loginEmail"
          aria-describedby="loginEmail"
          name="loginEmail"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
          {emailError && (
            <p className="error-message text-danger">
              Please provide a valid email address.
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <label htmlFor="loginPassword" className="form-label">
        Password
      </label>
      <input
        type="password"
        className="form-control mb-3"
        id="loginPassword"
        aria-describedby="loginPassword"
        name="loginPassword"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-primary mb-5 link-decoration-none"
        disabled={isPending}
      >
        Login
      </button>
      <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
        {errorMessage && (
          <p className="error-message text-danger">{errorMessage}</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <article>
        Don't have an account?{" "}
        <Link href="/sign-up" className="text-decoration-none">
          Sign Up
        </Link>
      </article>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Server response
loginUser.tsx:14 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status 401, [object Object]
at loginFunction (webpack-internal: